# How to trigger css :hover event on PageLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing an application where i want to open a cover on Pageload . Currently it is opening on hover. Also i want to bring out the page from inside to outside after opening the cover.

```
        <div id="onw" class="envelope">
          <p>From: <span>LOREM</span></p>
          <p>To: <span>IPSUM</span></p> 
      </div>
      <div class="open"></div>
        <div id="onee" class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
```

CSS is too long to copy here so i have copied my code into Jsfiddle

**JSFiddle Example :- http://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/4vs0r6zx/**

**If you dont agree with the question plz dont mark as a negative**

Thanx in Advance

Comment: just add the class you want with jquery?

Comment: @Stefan Added but not working . it would be helpful if you will help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `:hover` state and make the animation with another html-class. E.g. `.open.animateIt` contains the animation.

In this case you can make something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('.open').addClass('animateIt');
});
```

further you need some mouseenter/mouseleave events to trigger the animation after the first pageload.